# How to get the three UITextViews height by text content and change table view cell height by total 3 textViews height ios

Tags: objective-c

I have custom cell with 3 textViews:

[image]

I want to calculate the textview height of 3 textView and change tableView cell height dynamically and change height of textViews I am using this function to get the heigth for textViews

```
cell1.textValue1=[self calculateHeightForText:cell1.textView1.text indexPath:indexPath];
cell1.textValue2=[self calculateHeightForText:cell1.textView2.text indexPath:indexPath];
cell1.textValue3=[self calculateHeightForText:cell1.textView3.text indexPath:indexPath];



-(CGFloat)calculateHeightForText:(NSString*)text indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{  

UITextView *calculationView = [textViews objectForKey:indexPath];
CGFloat textViewWidth = calculationView.frame.size.width;
if (!calculationView.attributedText) {
    // This will be needed on load, when the text view is not inited yet

    calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    calculationView.attributedText =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    textViewWidth = 80;

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use autolayout constraints with unbreakable constraints or if you don't want to use autolayout constraints, then you calculate text height then manages all frames.

## pragma mark-heightCalculate

-(CGFloat)heightCalculate:(NSString *)calculateText {

```
NSString *text = calculateText;

UIFont *font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(yourtestfieldWidth, FLT_MAX);

CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

CGFloat height_lbl = size.height;

return (height_lbl);
```

}

Comment: by this i m getting height but when i am passing height to custom cell constraints it is not giving text view height according to text content.My 3 textviews properties
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tV1height;
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tV2height;

property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tV3height;

Comment: thanks man for textViews height it is working!!!! can u tell me how to calculate cell height by these 3 individual textViews height

Comment: according to text height change table view cell height.In below method -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 
    return height;
    
}

Comment: what height should i return

Comment: yes. But if you are using autolayout constraint, then you should use UITableViewAutomaticDimension with unbreakable constraints.All textview height and cell height get automatically managed.But constrains must be unbreakable.

Comment: bro can i have ur skype id

Comment: hello bro, my skype id- rohitchauhan853 and mob no:- 7508227106

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these methods

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension; }

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

If you have set number of lines in the UICell to 0 in interfacebuilder, the heights should be automatically adjusted to fit your label.You might have to put all three labels into one, to make this work.

EDIT:
If you have allready three strings in three labels, you could rewrite as follows:

```
 NSString*string1 =@"myfirstline\n";
    NSString*string2 =@"mysecondline\n";
    NSString*string3 =@"mythirdline\n";
    NSString*preCellString= [string1 stringByAppendingString:string2];
    NSString*CellString = [preCellString stringByAppendingString:string3];
    cell.textLabel.text = CellString;
```

The height of the tableviewcells should be automatically adjustet to fit your strings.

Comment: I have 3 textViews in one cell

Comment: by all 3 textview height i need cell height

Comment: Add the three textviews as subviews into the cell textviews. That should solve your problem. Or you could make the content of all three textviews into one NSString you set to the cell label.

Comment: can u give me sample for this..??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autolayout, then you should use below method with unbreakable constraints, not need to use height method.

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    return 85.0
}
```